# Flutter: Go_Router, BloC & Deeplinking issues with firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking, flutter-bloc

So, I have been working for about 3 days on this issue and i ran out of options on how to solve this.

basically, i have Firebase and im using go_router to handle deep links, it works well when the app is running and or if its on background, but once its killed (app is not opened), clicking a link does open the app, and does go to the assigned page, the problem is that it does not give enough time for the Firebase.initializeApp to complete and then it goes into that page, which results in an error of Firebase is not initialized.

I am using bloC, so i am instantly calling the Auth state to initialize both firebase amongst other things, and there seems to be no way to have it wait until the bloC state finishes and or just have async way of waiting for the firebase app to launch.

testing it as well is so horrible as i have to remove the app and install it again back and forth and build the app again on android which is pain.

so im wondering, is there any solution to this and am I going in the wrong direction here or what?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

shortly after i posted this, I realized that i should probably move

```
 await Firebase.initializeApp
```

to the top of `void main() async` rather than have it being called in a bloc event.